# Debian: Restart process when killed automatically in PuTTY

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, putty

I would like to know if there is any simple script to automatically restart a screened background process.

The process gets killed but couldn't manage to create a successful one :(.

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: 20 years ago for quake servers we'd start a screen session, and then in it do something like while true;do;./runquakeserver.sh;sleep 5;done - basically starting a loop that never ends, giving things a 5 second nap after the process is stopped (for whatever reason) and then restarting it

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the safest (but not the easiest) way to do this is to create a `cron` job to check if the process is running, and if it is not, restart it again. The reason why this method is "safer", is because if you use a loop like what `ivanivan` suggested and that script "crashes", the program will not be restarted again; on the other hand, by doing via `cron`, the check program will be called every minute.

For example, your `cron` could be:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /folder/testscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `env DISPLAY=:0` might not be needed in your case, or it might be needed, depending on your script (note: you might need to adapt this to your case, run `echo $DISPLAY` to find out your variable on the case).

For example, your `testscript` could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
testvar="$(ps aux | grep -s "mainscript" | grep -sv "grep -s mainscript")"
if [ -z "$testvar" ]; then nohup /folder/mainscript &; fi
#sleep and run second test
sleep 30
testvar="$(ps aux | grep -s "mainscript" | grep -sv "grep -s mainscript")"
if [ -z "$testvar" ]; then nohup /folder/mainscript &; fi
exit 0
```

On the example above, the `testscript` would check to see if the `mainscript` is running (and restart it if necessary) twice every minute.